# Covering Index - Insert Performance

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index-tuning, nonclustered-index

We are running some performance tuning on our database in SQL Server. The database in itself is pretty small with around 13 tables. But there are multi-level relationships between tables.

When I try to retrieve a top level object which contains many thousand rows of nested child objects, it took more than 4 seconds on an average. Looking at the trace files and query execution plan (and reading), I decided to make covering indices by doing this (to avoid Key Lookups) apart from the clustered index it already has on its Pkeys.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyTable_Cover] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
   Col0,Id
) Include ([Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col4])ON [PRIMARY]
```

Above is just an example, in my scenario, I have included about 18 non key columns. This resulted in 3x boost in response times. But when I do an insert of top level object (with nested children) the response time has increased by 4X. I understand more indices means, bad Insert Performance, but how I do I find the tradeoff in my case?.

Update: 
Here is my table structure with indexes

```
**Table A**
{AId, col1, col2, col3 ... col20}

Primary Index on AId

**Table B**
{AId, BId, col1, col2, col3 ... col20}
Primary Index on AId
Non-Clustered Index on BId

**Table C**
{BId, CId, col1, col2, col3 ... col25}
Primary Index on CId
Non-Clustered Index on BId

**Table D**
{BId, DId, col1, col2, col3 ... col 30}
Primary Index on DId
Non-Clustered Index on BId
Covering Index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_E] ON [dbo].[E]
(
   DId
) Include ([Col1],[Col2],[Col3] .. [Col30])ON [PRIMARY]

**Table E**
{BId, CId, EId, col1, col2, col3 ... col30}
Primary Index on EId
Non-Clustered Index on BId and CId
Covering Index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_E] ON [dbo].[E]
(
   EId
) Include ([Col1],[Col2],[Col3] .. [Col30])ON [PRIMARY]
```

I query for the top level object A which has all its children nested inside (usually it has 1000 rows of Table D and 1000 rows of Table D). I use Entity FrameWork to generate the query

Comment: You really should share your table structure of the involved tables, indexes, and your sample query for an accurate answer.

Comment: When you say Primary Index, are you indicating Primary Key, default clustered index?  Because this in and of itself will affect performance.  As JNK requests, more information is required to answer you adequately.

Comment: Sorry for being Cryptic, am trying to obfuscate my Table names and relationships as it is in Production. And yes I mean default clustered index when I say Primary Index. It is listed as PK_MyTableName (Clustered)

Comment: What exactly is your question?  "How do I find the tradeoff?" isn't very clear.  If you're trying to decide whether to keep the covering index, it depends on how important inserts are relative to queries.  I don't see how your covering indices on `D` or `E` are helping, as they duplicate the entire table.  What do your queries look like?

Comment: My questions is how many non-key columns is too much in a covering index. What is the cost of recreating these indices, when there is a new row added to the table?

Comment: Am doing a select (all columns) from E and select (all columns) from D, which is where I think the cover indices will come into play. Please correct me if am wrong

Comment: One option is to have unique clustered index with both of the IDs, for example in Table D: BId, DId? Then you wouldn't need the covering index.